# multiprocessing.Queue weird python behavior

Tags: python, printing, multiprocessing, queue

I stuck with understanding quite simple case.
Please, can someone explain or show the direction to understand the following:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_queue = mp.Queue()
    for i in range(5):
        input_queue.put([i]*5)
    print(input_queue.qsize())
    while not input_queue.empty():
        o = input_queue.get()
        print(o)
```

Output:

```
5
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

But:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_queue = mp.Queue()
    for i in range(5):
        input_queue.put([i]*5)
    # print(input_queue.qsize())
    while not input_queue.empty():
        o = input_queue.get()
        print(o)
```

Output nothing

Update:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_queue = mp.Queue()
    for i in range(5):
        input_queue.put([i]*5)
    for _ in range(5):
        o = input_queue.get()
        print(o)
```

Print expected output. So probably issue in .empty() method.

```
python --version
Python 3.6.9 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Comment: I'm getting the same output from the second case (minus the queue size) as expected. Maybe there's an issue with your print output target?

Comment: I don't think so, because in other cases is woks expectedly. I update my question with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be hitting [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues)

> After putting an object on an empty queue there may be an infinitesimal delay before the queue’s empty() method returns False

Can you try adding a sleep on the line before `while not input_queue.empty():`?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_queue = mp.Queue()
    for i in range(5):
        input_queue.put([i]*5)
    # print(input_queue.qsize())
    time.sleep(1)
    while not input_queue.empty():
        o = input_queue.get()
        print(o)
```

If the above works, then your `print(input_queue.qsize())` call in the first example is what is giving the queue enough time to pickle the objects and start returning `False` on the empty() call.

Comment: Happy to help! Can you also "accept" the answer? Thanks